# Should I switch from a TIP120 to a MOSFET?

Tags: arduino, transistors, mosfet, motor

I'm doing a project where I'm controlling how much voltage a 12 V, 3 A motor receives with a TIP120 Darlington transistor like in this picture:

[image]

The basis of the schematic (as I understand it) is to control how much voltage the motor will receive based on the value of the potentiometer. More info on the code or schematic is [here](https://dronebotworkshop.com/transistors-mosfets/).

The resistor is 2.2 kΩ and a IN4004 rectifier diode is used. While this works for a 6 V motor (as I have tried it), I wanted to know if this could also work with the motor I originally mentioned (with a 12 V, 3 A charger instead of 6 V) and if I need to change either the diode or the resistor to more fitting ones.

My other question is: After reading a bit in other threads about this transistor, I saw some people recommending using a MOSFET instead of the TIP120 (but I don't fully understand why) and I'm not sure if I should replace the transistor or just keep using it. Also, with a MOSFET, will it still be able to work as intended and which would be the best option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the [OnSemi TIP120 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tip120-d.pdf), you'll see that it's a Darlington transistor with the below internal schematic.

Darlington BJT pairs use the current gain of one Bipolar Junction Transistor (BJT) to drive a second BJT harder. The final gain is theoretically the two BJT gains multiplied, though in practice it's not as much as that. Here, your Darlington pair is on single silicon and package with some pull-down resistors for driving from low strength sources like logic gates.

The downside of a Darlington pair is that the second BJT's lowest Vce 'on' voltage is much higher than a single BJT. For small transistors, the Darlington Vce(on) might be 1 V instead of 0.3 V for a single driven BJT. Your TIP120 datasheet states a max. Vce(on) of 2.0 V when Ice is 3 A, 4.0 V when Ice is 5 A.

[image]

So at the max. Vce(on) of 2.0 V @ 3 A, that's a third of the drive power to your 6 V motor lost in the drive circuit and a sixth lost for a 12 V motor.

However, a power MOSFET can produce far lower 'on' voltage at 3 A, say, down in the tens of millivolts. So nearly all of the switched power gets delivered to the motor.

It is then straightforward to producing a single circuit that works with 6 V and 12 V supplies and motors, controlled from an Arduino 5 V GPIO pin configured as a General Purpose Output (GPO). The below circuit will switch at low frequencies for motor on/off control. You must choose a suitable N-channel power MOSFET that switches on strongly when driven with GPO at 4.2 V. The latter is a rough figure to allow for the Arduino supply tolerance and the GPO output losses. You can calculate your own more accurate value if necessary.

If higher frequency PWM driving is required, the MOSFET gate capacitance and GPO drive current must be considered to see if the switching times can be accommodated without excessive losses in the switching edges. Otherwise, a stronger MOSFET drive circuit or IC can be added to buffer the GPO current to a higher gate current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmsgWD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It would be useful to understand which values in a mosfet data sheet are relevent to this circuit. I need to select one for an identical conversion. MOSFET datasheets list drain current eg, 2A, gate source voltage eg 20-30V, drain source voltage. Are values close to the circuit values (eg 5-12v) ‘better’? Which ones might be critical for this circuit or are the tolerances sufficient that almost any going to be ok?

Comment: Hi @simoncoleman, that's fine, am happy to help, and we can do that in [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142627/room-for-tonym-and-simon-coleman) rather than in comments here.